# Django: Current login user in a query list

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

**model.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likecount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset= Question.objects.all(),
                template_name="index.html")),
```

**index.html**

```
{%for question in object_list %}
    {%for user_liked in question.like_set.all%}
      {% if user.username in user_liked.user.all%} `<!--if current logged in user in Like model user m2m field-->`
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-disable" name= {{question.id}}"id="request">Liked </button>  <!--disable like button-->
     {%else%}
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-enable" name= {{question.id}}"id="request">Like </button>  <!--enable like button-->
     {%endif%}
  {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Problem is **`if template tag`** block doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but like_set.all is not list of usernames, but list of users. Therefore check if user.username is in list of users fails. Check if user is in like_set.all.